# Why do some channel operations block and some don't

Tags: go

I've been seeing an inconsistency in the way that some articles (and golang's own documentation) describe channel operations and what I've seen in reality.

Its to do with how Go blocks on channel reads/writes. I've now read in multiple places that a goroutine blocks execution whenever it sees a read or a write to a channel meaning it either waits to receive data or it waits for another goroutine to receive data from the channel.

But if you look at the following example this is clearly not what's happening for the second write.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func firstFunc(ch chan string) {
    fmt.Println("firstFunc Hello", <-ch)
    fmt.Println("firstFunc() carries on getting called")
}

func secondFunc(ch chan string) {
    fmt.Println("secondFunc Hello", <-ch)
    fmt.Println("secondFunc() carries on getting called")
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("main() started")
    c1 := make(chan string)
    c2 := make(chan string)

    go firstFunc(c1)
    go secondFunc(c2)

    c1 <- "John"
    c2 <- "Bob"

    fmt.Println("main() ended")
}
```

This is how I'm interpreting that Go executes this code:

1. it prints the main() started messege, creates channel c1 and c2 and queues firstFunc and secondFunc goroutines (but doesn't execute them at this point)
2. it gets to c1 <- "John" and blocks it until another goroutine reads from that channel
3. at this point it schedules firstFunc which reads from c1 and carries on executing the rest of the code until the end of the function
4. main() is rescheduled again and the next line is C2 <- "Bob", at this point I would think that main() should block again like it did with "John" and wait for secondFunc to read from it before continuing. But this is not what happens. The output:

```
main() started
firstFunc Hello John
firstFunc() carries on getting called
main() ended
```

it doesn't simply block the write to "Bob" and instead carries on executing until main() is finished and never schedules secondFunc.

This has now become a road block for me in my learning of Go since I'm not sure whether it's the articles that I can't trust or if there is a gap in my understanding.

I would greatly appreciate some help on this.

Comment: [ask]: "*DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.*"

Comment: *queues firstFunc and secondFunc goroutines (but doesn't execute them at this point)* This is incorrect and it sounds like you're implying that the gourourines are waiting for something *in the code* to activate them. From the [docs](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Go_statements): *A "go" statement starts the execution of a function call as an independent concurrent thread of control, or goroutine, within the same address space.* You can think of goroutines as being executed, or scheduled for execution, immediately. The fact that a goroutine may have a blocking chan operation inside is irrelevant.

Comment: (continued) ... is irrelevant to when the goroutine is started and executed.

Comment: Yes I will update the images with text thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An unbuffered channel write will block until another goroutine reads from it. When that happens, both the reading and the writing goroutine are enabled. After that, there are no guarantees on how the execution will take place.

In your example, after `firstFunc` reads from the channel, it runs until it completes. The main goroutine writes to channel two, which enables `secondFunc`, but before it can have an opportunity to finish writing, main goroutine ends.

The problem here is that there are many possible orderings of executions, and you happened to observe one particular ordering.

Comment: Thabk you this exactly answered my question. I didn't read this in any of the docs, and it's made me think there is quite a lot I still don't know about the topic. Many thanks indeed

Answer (score 3):

It does not block for the reason that there are 2 channel listeners (firstFunc and secondFunc). These at random order read your message (whichever wakes up first). So the blocking is there, but not observable with active listeners. The only thing you will see is that sometimes you will see the output from firstFunc first and sometimes from secondFunc

Comment: How can you make both print? Using a lock maybe?

Comment: @jakub using a WaitGroup

Comment: @jakub You would have to add a waitgroup or read a channel response written back by the firstFunc/SecondFunc to guarantee execution before exit of the program

Answer (score 3):

You are not seeing output from `secondFunc` because main ends before it has the opportunity to execute. An easy way to fix this problem is to add `time.Sleep(time.Second)` before printing "main() ended."

The more correct way would be to use waitgroups, which would be like the following:

```
wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
wg.Add(2)
go func() { firstFunc(c1); wg.Done() }()
go func() { secondFunc(c2); wg.Done() }()
... // write to channels
wg.Wait() // This blocks till both the go-routines are done
```